# Extract Transact-SQL Event from tracefile using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have to play number of trace files created in SQL Server 2005 against 2008 and compare result of each statement. It is one of the proposed ways that migration went fine

In SQL Profiler menu I can go

*File/Export/Extract SQL Server Events/Extract Transact-SQL Events*

It creates nice script file where all T-SQL statements divided with GO 
I would like to get same result through the code since I have to process about 140 trace files 50MB each and number of them can vary.

If I export trace file into TraceTable for each SP I have about four records

RPC:Starting

SP:Starting

SP:Completed

RPC:Completed

In situation above extract produce just two lines

```
Exec some_sp
GO
```

I know how to read tracefile using SMO but again I have to create pretty sophisticated logic to properly pair and aggregate all Start/Complete events and not miss anything.

Does anybody knows hot to achieve extract T-SQL events using SMO and C# and delegate analysis of tracefile to SMO and/or Profiler API?

Comment: Why do you have to pair up the Start and Complete events, they are the same query, just pull out the completed events and ignore the start events.

Comment: in my original question all events doing same stored proc, however it can be inside other events whhic started eralier like  SQL:BatchStarting SQL:StmtStarting <here comes RPC SP pairs> SQL:StmtCompleted SQL:BatchCompleted Those events are about same sqlcommand profiler just cathes four events to execute just one sqlcommand